# Flickr api vs. Picasa api

Tags: api, flickr, picasa

I'm building an application where users can upload pictures. All I require is for the user to upload the initial photo, and manage the title, description, tags and spatial data for kml. The ability to upload videos would be nice.

These pictures will be used as part of a custom google map application.

I'm more interested in the effectiveness of apis vs. which service is better, as long as the above requirements can be met.

I've read that the Flickr api is great, but I'm looking for some firsthand info from those who have worked with both apis.

The other option is of course to manage this data inside the application.

I'm working with .net and jquery.

Thanks!

Comment: If your website is commercial then you should check the terms and condistions of both. I know Flickr's T&Cs prohibit commercial use, without their permission and when I asked they said 'No'.

Comment: Thanks Richard, that's a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided to go with Picasa, simply because I'm already using the goolge api with Youtube. Also, Picasa allows for simple google maps integration - all I have to do is add a GeoRss overlay to the rss feed from the album.